# Optimize external image that get loaded by javascript

Tags: javascript, google-pagespeed

i'm trying to get a decent google page speed rating but there are some issues with image from hello bar, that is blank and gets loaded by js. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
Losslessly compressing https://hey.hellobar.com/…
29b69ecb59172635a2069000255a32f4e61c8f8c could save 1,000B (91% reduction).
```

Comment: what type/extension the image is?

Comment: A potential 1KB optimisation of an image is not worth even looking at.  If you have speed issues that need to be resolved then I promise that's not what's causing them.  Bear in mind that Google's PageSpeed Insights gives warnings for lots of things, many of which are much less important than others.  This is one of those warnings.

Comment: When i save the image it suggests extension to be .gif, yes it doesn't have impact on the speed, just trying to get perfect insights score for my client, here is the image: https://hey.hellobar.com/v/8JxoCb7PWFM2JRFMS6SSS-ASvjjS/XUX93858fpS66-L1IuP6yVkjFQYjjeKUSJzdoVHvkvqFvi9qj96?a=lf%3A0%7Cnv%3A1%7Cns%3A0%7Crf%3A%7Crd%3A%7Cpp%3A%7Cpu%3Athesmartmoney.com.au%7Cpup%3A%2F%7Cdv%3Acomputer&t=1462269481&v=56f81eb3-5185-4d1b-c07a-f91fc62d01ee&f=i&s=d255141bf661e9c2cf4346b67894cfd516850f1426a35f78bc5c43772d8cd7357527d9e039d03b11c52be4fa0a35a518bd0132bd7b75558e834d0ccc56243722